# Is it possible to get the value of a SharePoint column in the worflow without any reference to the other table?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Is it possible to get the value of a SharePoint column in the worflow without any reference to the other table?

Here is my scenario...

```
List 1
Title
Status
Reminder 1 Date
Reminder 2 Date
Reminder 3 Date
Send Date


List 2
Title
Owner 
Supervisor 
Manager
```

My workflow is attached to List 1. When an item in List 1 is created the workflow triggers as follows

```
Pause until Reminder 1 
If Status = Open
Send Email to Owner
Pause until Reminder 2
If Status = Open
Send Email to Supervisor
If Status = Open
Send Email to Manager
Else
Terminate Workflow
Else
Terminate Workflow
Else 
Terminate Workflow
```

My "referencing" looks like this

```
Field Data to Retrieve
Data source: List 2
Field from source: Owner
Return field as: Email Address
Find the List Item
Field: Title
Value: List2:Title
```

My problem is, I get the "Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type."

I assume this is because both the titles of the lists have no relation.

How do I reference a column without the need of the "find the list" items.

Comment: I believe [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) is where to ask questions regarding `SharePoint`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinoon the error is realted to the blank lookup value available for the workflow when it is trying to send the email.

I think the Owner, Supervisor and Manager are the the Person or Group fields and one of them or all of them are not having a value , if that is the case then the value is not readable for the sharepoint workflow and it will throw the same error you are getting right now.

Have a look at this link for more idea about this.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ac6913c4-396b-4e7c-a42f-ee78656c7532/coercion-failed-unable-to-transform-the-input-lookup-data-into-the-requested-type

Please correct me if I am wrong or misunderstand your question.
Thanks

Comment: Oh apologies, I forgot to mention that the owner table already has a value.